# Como obtener dos campos de una misma tabla en SQL a traves de una consulta

Tags: sql

Lo que quiero es obtener de una misma `vista` o `consulta` dos campos de una misma columna pero con diferente valor, esto significa que debo de recuperar dentro de una misma columna dos valores diferentes, un valor es antiguo u obsoleto y el otro valor es el actual o nuevo y deben de estar en la vista para que se accede al obsoleto que se actualizo con uno mas nuevo.

Codigo Actual:

```
select p.numParte,f.alterno from DBEMPDEV.dbo.tMaestroPartes p
inner join DBSIADANA.dbo.tAlterno f on p.idNParte = f.idNParte;
```

El codigo de arriba me trae el `numero de parte` y mi `alterno`, solo que el alterno es un `id` y yo lo que quiero que salga en esa `consulta` son mis dos numeros de partes. Lo que quisiera saber es como con el id que obtengo de alterno puedo obtener el numero de parte actual dentro de el mismo campo de mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como actualmente obtengo el registro, el alterno que es un id debe ser sutituido por un numero de parte, solo se debe de sustituir en la consulta no de forma permanente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si entendí bien la pregunta, esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT P.numParte AS numParte, Q.numParte AS numParteAlterno
FROM DBEMPDEV.dbo.tMaestroPartes P
    INNER JOIN DBSIADANA.dbo.tAlterno F on P.idNParte = F.idNParte
    INNER JOIN DBEMPDEV.dbo.tMaestroPartes Q on Q.idNParte = F.alterno;
```

(suponiendo que `f.alterno` sea un `idNParte` en la tabla `tMaestroPartes`)

Comment: En efecto, esto suena a lo que busca OP. +1 Lo único que mejoraría es de asignarles aliases distintos a las 2 columnas seleccionadas para evitar amibiguidades al interpretar los resultados.

Comment: @sstan De acuerdo, agregado :)

Answer (score 0):

No sé de que tabla sea el alterno, pero si es de la misma que la primera, puedes intentar con esto

```
select p.numParte,
(select DBEMPDEV.dbo.tMaestroPartes.numParte 
   from DBEMPDEV.dbo.tMaestroPartes
   where DBEMPDEV.dbo.tMaestroPartes.idNParte = DBSIADANA.dbo.tAlterno.alterno)
as numParteAlterno
from DBEMPDEV.dbo.tMaestroPartes p
inner join DBSIADANA.dbo.tAlterno f on p.idNParte = f.idNParte;
```

Comment: El `from p` no me parece válido.

Comment: El problema es que no específico a donde hacia referencia el Id, de que tabla, solo es un ejemplo que bien puede adaptar @sstan

Comment: Aunque estoy de acuerdo con lo que dices de que sea solo un ejemplo, el poner `from p` en la sub-consulta da la impresión que puedes usar el alias de la parte principal de la consulta y usarla en el `from` de la sub-consulta, lo que no es correcto.

Comment: Me confundí, había visto claramente que era el nombre de la tabla, gracias por la aclaración y edito mi respuesta